# Agile Documentation Frameworks (NTestDox?)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, agile

I was reading this blog post: http://www.shakie.co.uk/ramblings/feature-driven-development-riding-the-waves-of-change/ and came across the part about TestDox:

Direct quote (hence PHP):

> Take the following test case as an
>   example

```
class InvoiceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testValueIsInitiallyZero() {
        $invoice = new Invoice();
        $this->assertEquals(0.00, $invoice->getValue());
    }

    public function testWillCloseAutomaticallyIfWholeValueIsPaid() {
        $invoice = Invoice::getInvoiceById(1);
        $invoice->payAmount(100.00);
        $this->assertEquals(true, $invoice->isClosed());
    }
}
```

> In the TestDox format this would
>   translate to:
>
> **Invoice**
>
> **[x] Value is initially zero**
>
> **[x] Will close automatically if whole value is paid**

This would be great on some of the more agile projects I'm working on. I've been looking at TestDox and trying to track down NTestDox as I'm a .NET guy.

3 questions in one here:

Anyone find a copy of NTestDox? (I'm seeing page does not exist on the only useful results in google)

- http://www.emxtechnologies.com/ntestdox
- http://www.projectdistributor.net/projects/Project.aspx?projectId=87

Is generating documentation from your Unit tests a good plan?

Does anyone know of any other frameworks for .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NTestDox I unfortunately can't help you, but nevertheless I'd like to answer your last two questions.

> Is generating documentation from your Unit tests a good plan?

Whether documenting exiting unit tests will do you any good, I do not know. There is however value to be had from being able to use human readable specifications as part of your test framework if you intend to develop test-driven. Have a look at [BDD](http://behaviour-driven.org/) and [ATDD](http://testobsessed.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/atddexample.pdf).

This leads to your second question:

> Does anyone know of any other frameworks for .NET?

If you look for the benefits of BDD instead of generating documentation from your tests, you could have a look at [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/). It should be usable with .NET (see documentation [here](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/ironruby-and-net)).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any usable traces of NTestDox either.

However I did find nAgileDox and [TestDox for .NET](http://www.testdox.com/) which is from early 2010.

Although the pages of Chris Stevenson's [AgileDox project](http://agiledox.sourceforge.net/) at sourceforge only mention his TestDox Java program for JUnit from 2003, the project's [CVS repository](http://agiledox.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/agiledox/) also contains the nAgileDox C# program with a Console version and a GUI version. Its last update is from 2007. Source and executables are available in the files nAgileSource.zip and nAgileComplete.zip from [this directory](http://agiledox.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/agiledox/nAgileDox/bin/).

Both nAgileDox and TestDox for .NET work by reading .net assemblies.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430036/convert-c-unit-test-names-to-english-testdox-style).